# Limit of a sequence that converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Exercise:

Let $ {(a_n)}_{n=0}^\infty$ be a sequence with $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 0.$ Then $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt{1 + a_n} = 1.$ 
Use this fact to compute the limit 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{1 + a_n} -1}{a_n}.
\end{equation*}

I tried to solve it like this:
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+a_n}-1}{a_n} = \\&
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+a_n}-1}{a_n} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{1+a_n}+1}{\sqrt{1+a_n}+1} =\\&
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\left(\sqrt{1+a_n}\right)^2-1^2}{a_n\left(\sqrt{1+a_n}+1\right)} =\\&
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1+a_n-1}{a_n\left(\sqrt{1+a_n}+1\right)} =\\&
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{a_n\left(\sqrt{1+a_n}+1\right)} =\\&
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a_n}+1} = \frac{1}{1+1} = \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}

But then again couldn't it just be like this:

\begin{align*}
&\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+a_n}-1}{a_n} = \\&
\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\sqrt{1+a_n}-1\right)}{\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n} = \\&
\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{1+a_n}-\lim_{n\to\infty}1}{\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n} = \frac{1-1}{0} = \frac{0}{0}.
\end{align*}

Which way is right and why?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You clearly cannot apply $\lim (a_n/b_n) = \lim a_n /\lim b_n$ in this scenario as $0/0$ is an indeterminate form.

Comment: It can not be applied since $b_n=0$, right. But is the other way correct? Thanks!

Comment: The other way is correct.

Comment: As a side note, presumably you need the additional hypothesis that $a_n \neq 0$ so the denominator of $$\frac{\sqrt{a_n + 1} - 1}{a_n}$$is nonzero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second method, you seem to have made the assumption that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{y_n}=\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}{x_n}}{\lim_{ n\to\infty}y_n}.$$
This is almost correct, except that we must assume that $x_n,y_n$ converge to a finite value and $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n$ is nonzero. This is a well-known result in analysis, see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685036/proof-regarding-the-algebraic-limit-theorem). So your first method is correct, but the second one is wrong  because you have applied this result in a place where it does not actually apply, as $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$.